# For a header background, does Javascript render faster than a straight image?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a header that is 10px tall, and the width of the browser window. It has a stripe pattern, that is repeatable on the x-axis.

At the moment I'm using [Patternizer](http://info.patternizer.com/) to fill the header using Javascript and some basic stripe rules.

But would a browser that has visited the site before render that faster than it would render a 20KB image repeating on the x-axis using CSS that had already been stored in the cache?

For reference, I'm talking about the header on [Markpond](http://markpond.com).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, for a 10px Header-image, a repeated background-image is just fine (unless you want a dynamic pattern or plan to change it a lot).
Since Patternizr uses a canvas-element, it will be 'slower' (to compute) on some Browsers and definitely 'slower' (to compute) mobile. There are also compatibility issues for older IE versions, but I'm not sure of the details.

But we are talking about micro optimization here. There won't be any big difference and I'm not sure why you even bother asking this question.

I recommend: Make a screenshot of your page now, load an image and kick patternizr.